# Serialized object with JSON not properly ended

Tags: json, struts, weblogic9.x

I have a Struts Action, that serves JSON data.
This data is serialized from a POJO with basic elements, using JSON.

In `localhost`, with Tomcat 6, system works correct, but when I deploy the app to Weblogic 9, the result from servlet, is not OK, the resulting JSON is not properly ended (it misses a }).

This is the pojo (I omited getters and setters)

```
public class DMTestResponse
{
    private String codiError;
    private String descripcioError;
    private Dades dades = new Dades();

    public class Dades
    {
            private String dada1;
            private String dada2;
            private Integer dada3;
            private String dada4;
    }
}
```

And this is the part of code that serializes the object:

```
@Override
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
    // Some things
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    os.write(resp.toString().getBytes(), 0, resp.length());
    os.flush();
    os.close();
}
```

From tomcat, the respose is:

```
{"codiError": "0", "dades": {"dada1":"bla", "dada2":"bla","dada3":"50";"dada4":"text llarg suspensió"}}
```

But from weblogic, the respose is:

```
{"codiError": "0", "dades": {"dada1":"bla", "dada2":"bla","dada3":"50";"dada4":"text llarg suspensió"}
```

How you can see, in weblogic, the last '}' is missing.

What may be the cause ?

Answer (score 0):

Different servers could be configured to for different encoding. Try

```
response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
String s = resp.toString();
byte[] ba = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
os.write(ba, 0, ba.length);
os.flush();
```